# jBPM 6.1 Hello World

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, drools, jbpm

I get the following error :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.12.Final}
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/JBPMorm.xml
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/Taskorm.xml
Nov 09, 2014 4:11:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryManager.getOrCreate(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:33)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.DefaultRuntimeEnvironment.init(DefaultRuntimeEnvironment.java:73)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.get(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:400)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.get(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:74)
    at main.java.ProcessTest.main(ProcessTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/jbpm-ds]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: unable to find a bound object at name 'jdbc/jbpm-ds'
    at bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext.lookup(BitronixContext.java:83)
    at bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext.lookup(BitronixContext.java:67)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
    ... 32 more
```

this is the code I'm using :

```
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.*;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.context.EmptyContext;

public class ProcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();
//        kieHelper.addResource(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("main/resource/Hello.bpmn"));
//        KieBase kieBase = kieHelper.build();
//        KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
//        ProcessInstance processInstance = kieSession.startProcess("com.sample.hello");
//        System.out.println("Process completed ? " + (processInstance.getState() == ProcessInstance.STATE_COMPLETED));
        RuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnvironment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
                .newDefaultInMemoryBuilder()
                .addAsset(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("main/resource/Hello.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2)
                .get();
        RuntimeManager runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(runtimeEnvironment);
        RuntimeEngine runtimeEngine = runtimeManager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());
        KieSession kieSession = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
        ProcessInstance processInstance = kieSession.startProcess("com.sample.hello");
        System.out.println("Process completed ? " + (processInstance.getState() == ProcessInstance.STATE_COMPLETED));
        runtimeManager.disposeRuntimeEngine(runtimeEngine);
        runtimeManager.close();
    }

}
```

and the `Hello.bpmn` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools" xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/drools" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd http://www.jboss.org/drools drools.xsd http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0 bpsim.xsd" id="Definition" expressionLanguage="http://www.mvel.org/2.0" targetNamespace="http://www.jboss.org/drools" typeLanguage="http://www.java.com/javaTypes">
  <bpmn2:process id="com.sample.hello" tns:version="1" tns:packageName="defaultPackage" tns:adHoc="false" name="Hello Process" isExecutable="true" processType="Private">
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="_1" name="Start">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_3" tns:priority="1" name="" sourceRef="_1" targetRef="ScriptTask_1"/>
    <bpmn2:scriptTask id="ScriptTask_1" name="Hello" scriptFormat="http://www.java.com/java">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:script>System.out.println(&quot;Hello&quot;);</bpmn2:script>
    </bpmn2:scriptTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_4" tns:priority="1" name="" sourceRef="ScriptTask_1" targetRef="EndEvent_1"/>
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_1" name="End">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
  </bpmn2:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1" name="Hello Process">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_Process_1" bpmnElement="com.sample.hello">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_StartEvent_1" bpmnElement="_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="45.0" y="45.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_ScriptTask_1" bpmnElement="ScriptTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="50.0" width="110.0" x="190.0" y="38.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_EndEvent_1" bpmnElement="EndEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="442.0" y="46.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_3" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_3" sourceElement="BPMNShape_StartEvent_1" targetElement="BPMNShape_ScriptTask_1">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="81.0" y="63.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="179.0" y="63.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="179.0" y="63.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="190.0" y="63.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_4" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_4" sourceElement="BPMNShape_ScriptTask_1" targetElement="BPMNShape_EndEvent_1">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="300.0" y="63.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="422.0" y="63.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="422.0" y="64.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="442.0" y="64.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

Is there problem with the imports? am I doing it wrong?

another question, 
in the jBPM 4, we were able to easily invoke a method from a specific class, but how do I do this in the jBPM 6?

thanks.

Comment: The Exception is because you are using the default persistence unit but it can't find the datasource definition. Can you post your persistence.xml file?